# Flutter receive emails

Tags: email, flutter, package, gmail, flutter-dependencies

I want to know if there is a package out there that allows people to receive emails / drafts / deleted items from for example gmail. I found something that seemed to attempt it but I think the support has stopped for it and also my gmail automatically blocks any login attempts from it (which I can evade but if I want to eventually release it then of course this is not the correct option)

The "Potentially non supported" package: [imap_client](https://github.com/michaelspiss/imap_client)

I was wondering if someone has found a better / new package that doesn't have that issue or if someone knows how to write one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't really understand if you want to send it using SMTP or if you want to open the mail app.

For sending programmatically: https://pub.dev/packages/mailer
To open the gmail app: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender

Comment: Well I want to make my own UI but be able to receive and send emails using my gmail account. If that clears it up a bit more

Comment: Then the first link should help you out

Comment: First one is only for sending? I also want receiving of emails

Comment: Oh I got you now, unfortunately I didn't find such a package because it probably doesn't exist yet. If you have some experience with basic networking I would suggest on expanding the `Mailer` package and providing support for that. That could really be a cool project and you'll help out a bunch of people in the future, good luck! If my solution helped yoy at all please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I'll look into expanding it but my dart skills aren't up to part I think. Although it will never hurt to try it I guess. Thanks for your help